# slack block text input not work in mobile app (android)

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

slack block text_input not work in mobile app(only android).
// IOS is work!

i send message to slack channel with block element.
it work well in desktop slack.
i can insert text to text_input.

but text is not inserted in text_input at slack mobile app(only android).

how to fix that?

```
[
    {
        "type": "input",
        "element": {
            "type": "plain_text_input",
            "action_id": "plain_text_input-action"
        },
        "label": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": ":slightly_smiling_face: insert your E-mail",
            "emoji": true
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "actions",
        "block_id": "block_id_Sys_airp",
        "elements": [
            {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Send"
                },
                "action_id": "approve_request",
                "value": "btn_Sys_airp_OK"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inquired about my problem with Slack, and it was confirmed that it was a bug.
They said they would solve the problem as soon as possible.